# Dynamically update UILabel's position on UIView depend on their text value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I am getting these values from web. This screen if all values came from web which looks cool.

[image]

And in absence of data it looks like follows.

[image]

I used this code

```
//Purchasae info
    {
        NSInteger heightToDecrease = 0;
        NSInteger heightToIncrease = 0;
        // NSInteger LABEL_HEIGHT = 18;

        maximumSize = CGSizeZero;
        textSize = CGSizeZero;

        //purchaseCostLabel
        heightToDecrease += self.PurchsCostHeightConstrains.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.purchaseCostLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.purchaseCostLabel.text font:self.purchaseCostLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger purchaseCostLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.PurchsCostHeightConstrains.constant = purchaseCostLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.PurchsCostHeightConstrains.constant;

        //insurance
        heightToDecrease += self.insuranceHeightConstraints.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.purchaseInsuranceLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.purchaseInsuranceLabel.text font:self.purchaseInsuranceLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger insCostLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.insuranceHeightConstraints.constant = insCostLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.insuranceHeightConstraints.constant;

        //shipping
        heightToDecrease += self.shippingHeightConstarants.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.shippingLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.shippingLabel.text font:self.shippingLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger shippingLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.shippingHeightConstarants.constant = shippingLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.shippingHeightConstarants.constant;

        //conservation
        heightToDecrease += self.conserVHeightConstraints.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.conservationLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.conservationLabel.text font:self.conservationLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger conserLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.conserVHeightConstraints.constant = conserLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.conserVHeightConstraints.constant;
        //storage
        heightToDecrease += self.storageHeightConstraints.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.storageLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.storageLabel.text font:self.storageLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger storagLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.storageHeightConstraints.constant = storagLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.storageHeightConstraints.constant;
        //Frameing
        heightToDecrease += self.framingHeightConstraints.constant;
        maximumSize = CGSizeMake(self.shippingLabel.frame.size.width, 999);
        textSize = [UtilityHandler textSizeOfString:self.shippingLabel.text font:self.shippingLabel.font maxSize:maximumSize];
        NSInteger framLabelHeight = textSize.height+SPACE_PADDING;
        self.framingHeightConstraints.constant = framLabelHeight;
        totalHeightToIncrease += self.framingHeightConstraints.constant;

        // set content view height constraint
        self.purchaseInformationViewHeightConstraint.constant -= heightToDecrease;
        // set content view height constraint
        self.purchaseInformationViewHeightConstraint.constant += heightToIncrease;


    }
```

So how do I update labels frame so if any label can take blank labels' positions?

Comment: Yes i am using autolayout

Comment: yes but not works well. 0.0 as it is cgfloat

Comment: have you considered using a single label for the purchase information? create a single string from the information you have (inserting the new lines) and set the string property of the single label

Comment: both some by storyboard and by code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Storyboard for your label and use only single label
Set your label to have all 4 constraints, left,right,top,bottom
Set number of lines 0.
It will work for your text