# Unable to set cell size according to label's text size in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying for chat app. Chat working fine. Facing some UI issues.

**1.** I am using auto layout for label. So automatically label get expand according to the message size. But, I am having label in UITableViewCell. I couldn't calculate row height dynamically.

My Code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CGSize textSize = {268, CGFLOAT_MAX};
CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGFloat height = size.height  < 65 ? 65 : size.height;
return height;
}
```

**My Label Sub class Code**

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    self.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.textInsets)];
}

- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
{
    self.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
    CGSize superSize = [super intrinsicContentSize] ;
    superSize.height += self.textInsets.top + self.textInsets.bottom ;
    superSize.width += self.textInsets.left + self.textInsets.right ;
    return superSize ;
}
```

The above code working for small messages, like 400 to 800 characters. More than that it is not working. Cell size not getting increase, as per label size. Kindly guide me.

**My Output:**

[image]

In the above screenshot, small messages displaying time and full message. If we type large text, 20% of message getting hide. kindly guide me. How to solve this?

Comment: see this short answer, if this could help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435024/dynamically-update-uilabels-position-on-uiview-depend-on-their-text-value/34436321#34436321
Added answer to cop with tableView

Comment: you can use size to fit property

Comment: you can add the cellforrowatindex code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Storyboard for your label and use only single label Set your label to have all 4 constraints, left,right,top,bottom Set number of lines 0.
In your ViewController use these 2 methods,Table view will automatically set height depend on your text

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. Its is working. But, while scrolling, cell size get decreased. Any idea.?? @Arslan Asim

Comment: Have you set all 4 constraints for label ?

Comment: Hi.. I have tried ur above code. Got output. I am facing another new issue. kindly help me in this. I am doing chat app. messages has been updated in last row of table view. I tried, but failed. pls help me in this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547969/swift-scrolling-issue-while-inserting-new-row-in-tableview