# Swift: Scrolling issue while inserting new row in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am doing chat app. I am having doubt in [Unable to set cell size according to label's text size in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530710/unable-to-set-cell-size-according-to-labels-text-size-in-objective-c/34530812?noredirect=1#comment56827063_34530812) .I have solved that issue.

Here, If I send new message, I have to insert new row as last row in tableview. I have tried with following code. But, tableview getting reload again while scrolling to last. UI is not seems good. Because, tableview falling from top. How to stop this? I am using auto layout. Gave constraints to **tblCellLabel (UILabel - Customized from Story board)** which is in UITableViewCell. I just want to insert a row in last without UI issue.

Kindly guide me how to solve this issue.

My Code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let  cellId:String = "Cell"+String(indexPath.row)
    var cell  = myTblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = tblCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId)
    }

    (cell as! tblCell).tblCellLabel.text = "hjgyrtjjjg12hjgyrtjjjg12hjgyrtjjjg12hjgyrtjjjg12hjgyrtjjjg12hjgyrtjjjg12"

    return cell as! tblCell
}

@IBAction func addRow(sender: UIButton) {
            self.inte = self.inte + 1
            self.myTblView.beginUpdates()
            self.myTblView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
                NSIndexPath(forRow: inte - 1, inSection: 0)
                ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            self.myTblView.endUpdates()
            self.scrollToBottom()  //HERE, TABLEVIEW FALLING FROM TOP. 
}
func scrollToBottom()
    {
        let numberOfSections = myTblView.numberOfSections
        let numberOfRows = myTblView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            print(numberOfSections)
            print(numberOfRows)
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))

            print(indexPath)

            myTblView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
        }
    }
```

**tblCellLabel-Subclass Code**

```
override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {

        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += insets.top + insets.bottom
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += insets.left + insets.right
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }
```

**My Output Screen Shot:**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you use scrollToBottom() after your updates if that's not what you want ?

Comment: I am doing chat application. So, last message should be update in tableview. So, I am inserting a row in last, and tableview scroll to last indexpath. Thats it.

Comment: Got solution ? Plz post ur answer . I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one helps you

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return inte
}
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell{

    let  cellId:String = "Cell"+String(indexPath.row)
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId)
    }
    let cellText:String = String(indexPath.row)

    (cell! as UITableViewCell).textLabel!.text = cellText

    return cell! as UITableViewCell

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
   @IBAction func addRow(sender: UIButton) {
    self.inte = self.inte + 1
    self.myTblView.beginUpdates()
    self.myTblView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
        NSIndexPath(forRow: inte - 1, inSection: 0)
        ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.myTblView.endUpdates()
    self.scrollToBottom()  //HERE, TABLEVIEW FALLING FROM TOP.
}
func scrollToBottom()
{
    let numberOfSections = myTblView.numberOfSections
    let numberOfRows = myTblView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

    if numberOfRows > 0 {
        print(numberOfSections)
        print(numberOfRows)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))

        print(indexPath)

        myTblView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried ur code. Working fine. But, I am using customized label. Check my question. I updated. Kindly help me.

Comment: @McDonal_11 , i suggest you ,use tableview cell id should be unique

Comment: I am using Custom table view cell. U r tryin for default tableViewCell. I have subclass my UITableViewCell as **myTableCell**  and, I have added UILabel to that class.kindly check my **cellForRowAtIndexPath** . There, I have subclassed my tableViewCell.

Comment: U r code is working well, for default. How to do that customised tableViewCell? pls guide me..

Comment: I didn't understand myTablecell, please share in detail

Comment: `let  cellId:String = "Cell"+String(indexPath.row)
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId)
    }
    let cellText:String = String(indexPath.row)

    (cell! as myTableCell).myLabel!.text = cellText

    return cell! as myTableCell `

Comment: instead of UITableViewCell, I have used, `myTableCell` . By doing this, am getting error on the line, 

 `(cell! as myTableCell).myLabel!.text = cellText  //FATAL ERROR:while unwrapping an optional value.`

I am facing this error.

Comment: here you have to create an object of type MyTableViewCell `let  cellId:String = "Cell"+String(indexPath.row)
        var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)// as! MyTableViewCell
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = MyTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier:cellId)
        }

        let cellText:String = String(indexPath.row)
        (cell as! MyTableViewCell).myLabel.text = cellText

        return cell as! MyTableViewCell`

Answer (score -2):

why are you using number of rows - 1 in scrollToBottom func

Comment: If this is intended to answer the question, please rewrite it to make it more explicit, as rhetorical questions often get mistaken for requests for clarification which are not supposed to be posted as answers.