# How to display paragraph of text on Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to display a paragraph of text to a `ViewController` with a `UILabel`, however the `UILabel` only stays on one single line even if I specify "0" lines (which should mean unspecified and flexible) in the `UILabels` attributes. What settings do I go about changing to allow the paragraph to automatically wrap the lines?

Comment: see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435024/dynamically-update-uilabels-position-on-uiview-depend-on-their-text-value/34436321#34436321

Comment: Does this work `yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping`? You can set this property in the storyboard as well.

Comment: You should check if you have the correct auto layout constraints so that the `UILabel` knows where to break the line.

Answer (score 3):

I think [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/) would be more appropriate, and best suites your requirement. The only thing you need to do is uncheck Editable to prevent user from editing displayed text. Any text greater than its size to be fit in would be scrollable, so you don't need to care about number of line etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel.sizeToFit()
```

use this code and replace `UILabel` to your label object.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @boidkan, you have to set both `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` to get a multi-line display.

If you want to set the multi-line text statically in Interface Builder, you cannot directly type it into the attributes inspector (pressing enter will end editing instead of creating a newline); instead you have to type it in some text editor and copy-past it into IB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can enter a new line by holding either option or shift (not sure which) while you press enter, very much like in excel or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all 4 constraints (Top , Right , Bottom , Left ) for the label you want to make as a paragraph and set you maximum number of lines to 0 and it will work (This worked for me )

Answer (score 0):

Using UILabel setting 0 as the 'Lines' (the number of lines) in the attribute inspector makes it adapt accordingly. However you must tell Xcode when to break the line using 'Line Break' (also in the attribute inspector). Word wrap breaks the line at the last word that will fit in the text box for the width you have specified.